# Notification on slack channel moving a Jira ticket to custom column

Tags: jira, slack

How can I get notifications from Jira to a Slack channel moving a ticket to a custom column - e.g. **"awaiting code review"** ?

From the Slack-Jira plugin documentation (https://slack.com/apps/A0F7YS3MZ-jira) I read:

"This integration will allow you to receive updates in a Slack channel for the following JIRA events:

• An issue is created or re-opened

• An issue is closed (unless it was previously resolved)

• An issue is updated to done or resolved

• An issue is updated to in progress or to do after previously being marked as done

More statuses and transitions will be supported in a future update to the JIRA integration."

And I know we can easily get notified for push and pull requests.

I saw it in action on one of my previous projects but I can't figure out how to do it.

Thanks

Comment: This could help: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/12782115/how-can-i-customize-jira-agiles-slack-integration

Answer (score 2):

A solution that could work for this scenario is:

- Get JIRA to send an email on status change to "awaiting code review" https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/169599/send-an-email-notification-when-the-issues-status-change
- Just send the email to a Slack channel >> https://slack.com/apps/A0F81496D-email in order to display it.

**UPDATE**:
Doesn't seem to work. The solution is to write a small app that consumes from Jira and send notications to slack..

**UPDATE-2**:
It seems that the jira-slack plugin now allows to setup such notifications.
**The steps explained [here](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/218475657-Posting-JIRA-updates-to-Slack) worked for me**.

Plugin for Slack: https://slack.com/apps/A0F7YS3MZ-jira

Plugin for Jira: https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/eu.wisoft.slack.jira/cloud/overview

Note: you need **admin access to Jira**